# How to extract first 5 characters from filename in LogicApps

Tags: filenames, azure-logic-apps

I have an issue, could you help me to understand how to extract first 5 characters from the filename in LogicApps. I'm able to create a variable and append it, so I have the list with file names, but then struggling to extract specific characters...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the **take** expression:

```
take(variables('my_string'),5)
```

This also work for arrays if you want to return the 5 first array items.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `substring` expression ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#substring

```
substring('<text>', <startIndex>, <length>)
```

The expression within the **First 5 Characters** variable for the below result looks like this ...

```
substring(variables('String Variable'), 0, 5)
```

**Result**

[image: Result]